# Form is submitting to another page without validation in php

Tags: php, html

This is the code i have used for online Registration
Validation is not working when i submit it another page,form is submitting to another page without any validation.i just need too know how to submit it with validation, can some one help out

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $cnameErr = $mobilenoErr = $emailErr = $cityErr= $postalcodeErr = $addressErr = "";

$name = $cname = $mobileno = $email = $city= $postalcode = $address = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) { 
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["cname"])) {
     $cnameErr = "Company Name is required";
   } else {
     $cname = test_input($_POST["cname"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["mobileno"])) {
     $mobilenoErr = "Mobile Number is required";
   }else {
     $mobileno = test_input($_POST["mobileno"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[789][0-9]{9}$/",$mobileno)) {
       $mobilenoErr = "Not A Valid Number"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
     $cityErr = "City is required";
   }  else {
     $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
       $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["postalcode"])) {
     $postalcodeErr = "Postal Code is required";
   } else {
     $postalcode = test_input($_POST["city"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
     $addressErr = "Address is required";
   } else {
     $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
   }
}


function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="div1" class="fluid"><!-- header ends here-->
    <div id="header" class="fluid">
      <div class="fluid logo_container zeroMargin_tablet">
      <div class="fluid logo_mvc"></div>
      <!-- logo_mvc ends here-->
      <div class="fluid logo_gsm"></div>
      <!-- logo_gsm ends here-->
    </div>
    <!-- logo_container ends here-->
</div>
    <div class="fluid imageslide zeroMargin_desktop">
      <div class="fluid imageslide_gs zeroMargin_desktop"></div>
      <!-- imageslide_gs ends here-->
      <div class="fluid imageslide_content">
      <h1>IP Product Introduction and VoIP PBX
Appliance Training Day @ Toronto</h1>
      </div><!-- imageslide_content ends here-->
      <div class="fluid imageslide_product"></div>
      <!-- imageslide_product ends here-->
    </div><!-- imageslide ends here-->
    <div class="fluid content">
    <div class="fluid content_det">
    <h3>Event information</h3>
    <p>Please join us at the Fairfield Inn & Suites Toronto Airport where Grandstream will offer four different sessions during the day. </p>
    <h3>Introduction to Grandstream IP products</h3>
    <p><b>8:45am - 10:15am</b><br/>
Introduction to Grandstream, and basic information on Grandstream products including ATAs, gateways, routers and telephones. </p>
<h3>Introduction to IP cameras IP and Surveillance products</h3>
    <p><b>12:45pm - 2:15pm</b><br/>
Basic information on IP cameras and surveillance products, and the introduction of the brand new GVR3550 Network Video Recorder. </p>
<h3>Advanced Technical Training for UCM VoIP PBX's</h3>
    <p><b>2:30pm - 4:30pm</b><br/>
This session will focus on the advanced features of the UCM series, including the new features of the upcoming software and the brand new UCM6510 VoIP PBX for T1 networks. </p>
    </div><!-- content_det ends here--><div class="fluid contet_form">
    <h2>Register Now</h2>
    <form method="post" action="Submission.php">
    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>First name *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>

    </div>


    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Company Name *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="cname" placeholder="Enter Your Company Name Here" value="<?php echo $cname; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $cnameErr;?></span></div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Mobile Number *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="mobileno" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number Here" value="<?php echo $mobileno; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $mobilenoErr?></span>
     </div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Email Id *:</b></label>
    <input type="email" size="20px" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span></div>


    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>City *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="city" placeholder="Enter Your City Name Here" value="<?php echo $city;?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $cityErr?></span></div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Postal Code *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="postalcode" placeholder="Enter Postal Code Here" value="<?php echo $postalcode; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $postalcodeErr?></span>
     </div>

    <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Address *:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="20px" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address Here" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $addressErr?></span></div>


<button name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div><!-- contet_form ends here-->
    </div><!-- content ends here-->
  </div><!-- div1 ends here-->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: check your `action` in form attribute to see whether that is the target file or not.

Comment: you must validate in Submission.php and optionally via javascript in the form page

Comment: Add above validation things in to the Submission.php page

Comment: @PacketTracer any method which can be validated in the form page and submitted to the different page

Comment: hi sandeep you should use client side validation with javascript or jquery also

Comment: @Robin you mean i have to validate in submission page as well as form page

Comment: you should use a javascript file and call it in your  html form page using the <script></script> tag, in the javascript file you should write methods which get called when the submit button is clicked and then the method will check the form input fields for proper values

Comment: this is client side validation and you can stop a form from submitting if validation fails.

Comment: just remove the action and validate your form and then redirect to Submission.php, after that you add js validation to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems you are new to PHP form handling. For beginners reinventing the wheel and is dangerous as it's so easy to open up security flaws in your script. Use a framework or CMS that can handle forms for you (e.g., [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) and [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) or just use something easy as [Zebra Form](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-form/) or something complete like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) or [Symfony](http://symfony.com/).

Just don't do everything yourself unless you really know what you are doing. It might take some time to get started, but it will definitely pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The validation has to happens when the request reaches the server. Your flow is like:

form displayed in browser -> user clicks submit -> data submitted to Submission.php -> validation should happen here.

Put your validation code in Submission.php.

Comment: Validate ur data then redirect to submission

Comment: Or just use the same script! First test whether if it's a POST request, if so, then validate and save the data if it's correct, if not, display the form and the error messages - if any. $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] tells you whether the method is GET or POST.

Answer (score 0):

Carefully check your action in form attribute. If you mention page name in form attribute then it will submit another page without validation. If you want validation in same page then remove page name from your action in form attribute. Other wise put validation checking in another page, which is mention in your action in form attribute.